# Modfiy index.html on AWS Amplify

Tags: html, reactjs, aws-amplify

Is there anyone here that has tried to modify the index.html file in a React project, after the build is done on AWS amplify?

I've played around to basically, change the  tags.

On two separate aws accounts, i've pushed the same repo. In the root folder, i've set up two different html files for the different accounts.

In the build, i've simply overwritten the content in the buid/index.html after the react build is done. And the funny thing is that it works, and my website loads the different html files, but all of react code is not simply working.

And i had checked all the redirects/rewrites for amplify and so on, just curious if anyone here has done something similar and actually made it working?